# Параметризованный Класс Java, ограничивает применение дженериков в его методах

Tags: java, generics

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Concrete{

}

class GenericsClass<T> {

    public <T> void some(){

    }

    public ArrayList<Concrete> another(){
        ArrayList<Concrete> list = new ArrayList();
        list.add(new Concrete());
        return list;
       //return Collections.singletonList(new Concrete()); //Компилируется 
       //только если убрать тип <T> у GenericsClass
    }

}

public class GenericsMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GenericsClass genericsClass = new GenericsClass();
        Concrete concrete = genericsClass.another().get(0);
   }
}
```

Почему если класс параметризован, то его метод параметризованной по конкретному классу уже отдаёт Object, а не Concrete конкретный класс? В данном примере, если GenericsClass не параметризован, то всё будет ОК

Comment: ага, если инстанциировать класс например так:         GenericsClass<String> genericsClass = new GenericsClass(); то всё работает, т.е. если класс параметризован, необходимо его инстанциировать обязательно с типом, иначе его методы, даже если у них конкретные типы прописаны, отдавать будут Object

Comment: А зачем вам нужны дженерики у класса?

Comment: Попробуйте у AL поставить <T> и посмотрите, что получиться.

Answer (score 1):

java стирает информацию о дженериках (type erasure) в параметризированном классе, даже в тех методах в которых тип отличается от типа класса, немного не логично, но это так работает, так что ваш метод возвращает

```
ArrayList<Object>
```